# code execution informatica workflow to run in 2 environments without disabling of the workflow from either of environment

Tags: environment-variables, informatica

I am moving informatica  one workflow from environment 1 to environment 2.
This informatica workflow has dependency of other workflows while running
Hence when this workflow is moved to environment 2 I need to write some sort of code in the environment 1 workflow that run this particular workflow should get trigger in environment 2 without disabling the workflow in environment 1
Any help will be much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this has always been an problem for lot of tools. When you migrate from prod to test/dev, you see similar issue in scheduling in test/dev. Now, you have below options you can do after migration after migration.

Option 1 - Official  way -
step 1 - list down the list of workflows. use below command to list down all workflows.
`pmrep listobjects -o workflow -f <folder name>`

step 2 - unschedule all workflows -
`pmcmd unscheduleworkflow ...`

Option 2 - Un Official  way -
if you are using scheduler option in informatica then you can use this option to disable all. update metadata table to unschedule all workflows at once using below SQL.

```
UDATE OPB_SCHEDULER
SET OPB_SCHEDULER.RUN_OPTIONS =1
WHERE   OPB_SCHEDULER.IS_VISIBLE = 1

;
```

You can check this view - REP_ALL_SCHEDULERS after changing.

To be on safe side, please change all source+ target connection info/password of environment 2 to lower instances like Dev.